# Rails way to make a find joining tables (Using .find method)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, model

I have the following tables:
**UserAction:** 
type_action: string
entity_id: int
date: datetime
user_id: int  (references User)

**Question:**
text: string
user_id: int (references User)
answered: tinyint

**EntityTracker**
type_track: string
entity_id: int
action: string 
date: datetime

I need to know how many (count) records are in EntityTracker(alias et) that meet this conditions:
- action = 'ANSWERED' 
- type_track = 'QUESTION'
- date > than (date of record in UserAction (alias ua) with ua.entity_id=et.entity_id and ua.type_action=et.type_track)
- entity_id meets the condition: Question with id=et.entity_id has user_id=params[:user_id]

So I have to join with Question and UserAction.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
EntityTracker.find(:all,
                   :from => 'entity_trackers et',
                   :select => 'COUNT(et.id) AS count',
                   :conditions => ['et.action = ? AND
                                    et.type_track = ? AND
                                    et.date > (SELECT MAX(ua.date)
                                               FROM user_actions ua
                                               WHERE ua.entity_id=et.entity_id AND
                                                     ua.type_action=et.type_track) AND
                                    EXISTS (SELECT questions.id
                                            FROM questions
                                            WHERE questions.id=et.entity_id AND
                                                  questions.user_id=?)',
                                   'ANSWERED', 'QUESTION', user_id])
```

Comment: How can I manage the condition that nested select :  select max(..... ) can be null? 
Something like et.date > (SELECT max....) when not null

Comment: That is database engine dependent, for example for MySQL you can use IFNULL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull